# Crash upon reading large PCap file

Tags: c++, pcap

I'm running the following code in C++ to read the packets inside a PCap file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcap.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, inum,i  = 0;
    pcap_if_t *alldevs;
    pcap_t *adhandle;
    struct bpf_program fcode;
    bpf_u_int32 net, mask;
    char *dev;
    string file = "C:\\Users\\AwesomeUser\\Desktop\\dataset.pcap";
    char errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t * pcap = pcap_open_offline(file.c_str(), errbuff);
    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
    const u_char *data = NULL;
    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuff);


    if (pcap_lookupnet( dev, &net, &mask, errbuff ) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't get netmask for device %s\n", dev);
        net = 0;
        mask = 0;
    }


    u_int packetCount = 0;

    cout << "Pre-loop test";
    while( int returnValue = pcap_next_ex( pcap , &header, &data) >= 0)
    {
        cout << "inner loop test";
        if (pcap_compile(pcap , &fcode, "ip and tcp", 1, net) < 0)
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "\nC++ is unable to compile the packet filter. Please check the syntax\n");
            pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
            return -1;
        }

        if ( pcap_setfilter( pcap, &fcode) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nThere is an error in setting the filter.\n");
            pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
            return -1;
        }

        printf("Packet number %i\n", ++packetCount);
        printf("Packet size: %d bytes\n", header->len);
        if ( header->len != header->caplen)
            printf("Warning! Packet size different from capture size: %ld bytes\n", header->len);

        printf("Epoch time: %d:%d seconds\n\n\n", header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec);

    }
    cout << packetCount;
    cin >> num;

    return 0;
}
```

The program crashes with the following output:

```
Pre-loop test
```

I've determined the crash occurs upon executing the condition of the while loop the very first time:

```
pcap_next_ex( pcap , &header, &data)
```

As far as I know, pcap_next_ex is supposed to read the next packet. I've tested this exact code with other .pcap files and it works flawlessly with everything I've tried from the internet and with files I generate myself using Wireshark. The only difference I'm aware of is that the dataset.pcap file I'm trying to read in this code is very large (8GB). Is there something special I need to do in order to read such a large file? What else might be causing the crash?

Comment: are you sure about the operator precedence in `int returnValue = pcap_next_ex( pcap , &header, &data) >= 0` resulting in a meaningful condition? ( I am not )

Comment: @tobi303 I tried `while( pcap_next_ex( pcap , &header, &data) >= 0)` which had the same effect in all cases